# Mounting two partitions on a pen drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, encryption

I have a 8 GB pen drive with two partitions on it, one of 20 MB and the other of the remaining space (7+ GB). Windows detects only the first partition. How can I mount the second partition?

Answer (score 1):

A complete format is a complete format, so to somehow have data survive this, you'd somehow need to convince the system that those sectors are bad (and remain so - which is harder!), and that should, in theory not get picked up by standard hard drive utilities.

This is not really a trivial task - this is one example with a linux file system, that uses a badblocks file to [create a set of clusters marked bad](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2009/04/22/hide-data-in-bad-blocks/) and the equivilent for windows, which uses a low level NTFS editor to edit file system metadata ([see the appendixes](http://www.forensicfocus.com/downloads/ntfs-hidden-data-analysis.pdf)). In addition some would you *notice* the larger part of the drive's space is missing. A formatting option that rechecks for bad blocks (a windows non quick format, or a linux format with the right option) would probably catch the fact that they are not actually bad blocks.

In short? If you want a file system that survives a reformat, you need to go for a proper, readonly media option (so it can't be overwritten) with some form of encryption- everything else is insufficiently foolproof

Now if you just wanted to hide a partition from casual view, you could probably use [diskpart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)  or some other partition editor such as [EaseUS partition tool](http://www.partition-tool.com/) to set it as hidden. This wouldn't make it impossible to format (you can see that there's a hidden partition from the disk manager snapon), but it would keep the drive from showing up as a drive letter, so would make it a little harder to accidentally format.

Comment: I Actually Want to Create Two Partitions on my USB, I know Windows Recognizes just the First Partition, I want to Mount the Second Partition also, but Only on this Machine...

Comment: Also, please refrain from misusing capital letters. It makes you a lot harder to read. In addition your question asks about *hiding* a partition, not mounting it. I'd edited my answer somewhat, to try to reflect other options, but "I want to mount a second partition on a USB device" is not the same as "I want to hide a partition" at all

Comment: I have Changed the Question, Now Can You Suggest anything.